# Simulation of Sockets in Network Simulator

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, simulator, ns-3

I want to simulate some nodes with Network Simulator(NS-3). The communication between them is UDP traditional socket. i want to know, for simulation is it 
enough to simulate from Transport Layer till Application Layer or is needed also to simulate Physical and Data-Link Layer of OSI Layers?

Answer (score 1):

NS3 is complete OSI layer simulation from Application Layer to Physical Layer. Thus, you need specify on what kind of network component that is your simulation run. It can be a very simple setup to do that using NS3 helpers API.

Here is a very simple UDP simulation example on NS3 : 
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/doxygen/first_8cc_source.html

The toturial is in here :
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.23/tutorial/singlehtml/index.html#a-first-ns-3-script